# Formatear estilo strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa, el cual contiene una función llamada funcion_ejemplo
la cual debe tomar como parámetro una string cualquiera.

Si dicha string está compuesta solo por vocales, la funcion debe devolver Verdadero o Falso. Se debe considerar todas las vocales tanto en mayúscula como en minúscula, acentuadas o no, y la u con dieresis ("aeiouüáéíóúAEIOUÜÁÉÍÓÚ").

```
input = ("oÉÜÍÓióáAoiueiüoeaéíió")  → True
input = ("Ejemplo de prueba para el ejemplo") → False

import archivoUV

print(archivoUV.funcion_ejemplo("aeouieeÍo"))
print(archivoUV.funcion_ejemplo("Frase sencilla para comprobar el resultado del ejercicio"))
```

Mi problema esta en que no se como pasarle el parametro a la funcion, ya que no veo ninguna variable creada que referencie esa string que pide. ¿Despues a esto habría que comprobar si ese parametro es un caracter que esta en el alfabeto con el metodo de string .isalpha()?

Tengo la idea pero no se como ejecutarla, dado que no se como pasarle el parametro. Mi idea seria tal que asi:

```
def funcion_ejemplo(parametro):
  for i in parametro:
    if i parametro.isalpha():
       return Verdadero
  else:
    return Falso
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, lo que quieres saber es como pasarle un parámetro a una función. Eso se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
def función(parámetro1,parametro2)
    resultado = parametro1 + parametro2 # aqui iría el codigo que detecta si son vocales    
    return(resultado) # esto asigna a la funcion el valor de resultado

suma = función(5,7)
```

Por lo que tu código quedaría así:

```
def are_vocals(string):

   accepted_digits = ["a","e","i","o","u"," "]

    answer = True
    for i, digit in enumerate(string):       
        if digit not in accepted_digits:     
            answer = False
            break      
    return(answer)

print( are_vocals("hola que tal"))
```

Comment: @Lorena eso es justamente lo que hace el programa en esta linea: are_vocals("hola que tal"). Donde dice hola que tal tienes que pasarle tu string. accepted_digits son los digitos que el programa cuenta como vocales.

Comment: ¿Y sin realizar llamada a la función, se podría hacer?

Comment: @Lorena si tu pregunta es si se puede resolver el problema sin una función, claro que se puede. Pero justamente las funciones existen para evitar repetir código muchas veces, además de hacer los programas más legibles

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `all()` para que devuelva `True` si todos los elementos de un iterable son `True` y así evitas utilizar una función (como has puesto en los comentarios):

```
vocales = 'aeiouáéíóúAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚüÜ'

texto_a_comprobar1 = 'bshduhfdfgdfgdfgoselm'
texto_a_comprobar2 = 'oÉÜÍÓióáAoiueiüoéíió'


print(all(t in vocales for t in texto_a_comprobar1))  #>> False
print(all(t in vocales for t in texto_a_comprobar2))  #>> True
```

Aunque como te han dicho, si vas a usarlo mucho, es mejor que tengas una función:

```
def funcion(texto_a_comprobar):
    return all(t in vocales for t in texto_a_comprobar)


print(funcion(texto_a_comprobar1))  # >> False
print(funcion(texto_a_comprobar2))  # >> True
```

**Empleando la función que habías hecho**

También puedes utilizar la función que habías empezado a hacer pero con una cierta modificación:

```
def funcion(texto_a_comprobar):
    for i in texto_a_comprobar:
        if i not in vocales:
            return False
        return True


print(funcion(texto_a_comprobar1))  # >> False
print(funcion(texto_a_comprobar2))  # >> True
```

Va recorriendo el `texto_a_comprobar` caracter a caracter, y si encuentra uno que no está en `vocales` devuelve `False` (y termina de ejecutarse la función), si todos los caracteres están en `vocales`, devuelve `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir la función con un `for` que recorre el string ingresado y valida si cada valor es una vocal respondiendo True o False y con `all()` determinar si existe un solo False (una sola letra que no es vocal) la respuesta es False, si todos son vocales será un True, luego al llamado de la función le envias el valor ingresado en el input e imprimes el return de la función, de la siguiente manera:

```
def validarVocales(parametro):
    vocales = 'aeiouüáéíóúAEIOUÜÁÉÍÓÚ'
    return all(v in vocales for v in parametro)

print(validarVocales(input()))
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludo!